# Which are the correct Google+ scope variables to get email address and to post?

Tags: google-plus, spring-social, spring-social-google

I'm using spring-social-google (built from the git repo) to allow people to sign into my Spring MVC application (I already have facebook, twitter and linedin working). The form below allows me to authenticate, but an email address is not returned and posting to the Google+ timeline is prohibited:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/register/social/${providerId}" />" method="POST" id ="${providerId}Form" name = "${providerId}Form">
    <button type="submit"><img src="<c:url value='/resources/${providerId}/sign-in-with-${providerId}.png'/>" border="0"/></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" />                   
</form>
```

I think the issue is that I don't have the correct scope variables. I've tried some of the combinations here https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth but I get told that the scope variables are all wrong. Which ones do I need?

This is the code for I'm using to get the email address:

```
public final class LoginConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp 
{   
    public String execute(Connection<?> connection) 
    {
        final UserProfile up = connection.fetchUserProfile();
        final String email = up.getEmail();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You say you "get told the scope variables are all wrong". Please edit the question to indicate what error or message you're getting.

Comment: Please also show the code for how you're trying to get the email.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here:

Posting to the Google+ Stream isn't supported by Google's API at this time. The package appears to let you create "app activity moments", which are stored on the user's profile... but these aren't posts to the stream. In order to generate an app activity, you need to include the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope.

Additionally, you can include either the `email` scope or the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` scope. With these scopes, you should be able to get the email address as part of the call to

```
Person person = google.plusOperations().getPerson("me");
```

So your input tag should probably look something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" />
```

(note the space between the two scopes to use).

**Important note**: The documentation talks about getting the email via a call such as

```
GoogleUserInfo userInfo = google.userOperations().getUserInfo();
```

while this may work for now, it is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in September. The userinfo scopes are also set to be deprectaed at this time. *Don't use this method or these scopes.* (And contact the author to tell them to deprecate it.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it didn't work for me. Luckily I tried a few more things and it appears that the scope variable I need is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email". This gives me the email address back. It's shame that posting isn't supported yet.

Comment: The userinfo scopes are set to be deprecated (see my important note) and should be avoided. If the other methods that get email as part of the user profile aren't working with spring-social-google, they should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. The key thing for me was to specify `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/` in front of the scope.  For example, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` rather than just `plus.profile.emails.read`.